# How to store downloaded file local url in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, react-native

i want to store the url path of downloaded file in mongodb so i can later use the path to open the file in my app.

i tried to store but the problem is whenever i download new file it upadate with the previous one .

this is the backend code

```
router.post('/download',function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body)
  User.updateOne({_id:req.body.userid},{$set:{downloadurl:req.body.downloadurl
  }}).then((user)=>{
    console.log(user);
    res.status(200).send({
  data:user,
  message:'success'
})
  }).catch((err)=>{
   console.log(err)
    res.status(500).send({
      data:err,
      message:'not success'
    })
  })

});
```

this is the backend of ui

```
export async function DownloadUrl(data) {

   let result = await fetch(url + 'user/download', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
         Accept: 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
   }).then(response => response.json());

   console.log(result);
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Well, the problem seems to be your schema. If you want to store multiple url paths inside a `User` document (Is this the approach you want?), you should have `downloadurl` as an array, instead of a plain field.

Comment: @Caconde i tried but the problem is that when next time im doing this its updating the previous url

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your urls are being stored in a plain text field. You need to store them in an array and, instead of using [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/), that will overwrite the previous data, start using [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/), that will append data to your url array:

```
router.post('/download',function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
    User.updateOne(
        {_id:req.body.userid},
        {$push:{download_urls:req.body.downloadurl}}
    ).then((user)=>{
        console.log(user);
        res.status(200).send({
            data:user,
            message:'success'
        })
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).send({
            data:err,
            message:'not success'
        })
    })
});
```

This way, you will end up with a `User` document like the one below:

```
{
    "_id": "some_id_value",
//  [...]
    "dowload_urls": [
        "someurl1",
        "someurl2",
        "someurl3"
    ]
}
```